# Please is it possible to move my migrations folder into a subfolder and flask updates this change

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I wanted my Flask app to be much clearer so i created subfolders and moved different aspects of my flask app i.e the routes, forms, models into diff python files and made use of the **init** file

but since i moved everything including the migrate folder into a subfolder, running flask db migrate is giving me errors

i am getting this error everytime i execute this command:

flask db migrate

Error: Path doesn't exist: 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Flaskblog2.0\migrations'.  Please use the 'init' command to create a new scripts folder.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `-d` option with the directory that you use for your migration repository. For example:

```bash
flask db migrate -d some_folder/migrations
```